# ASP page - Lengthy code behind firing button click

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, performance

I have some asp.net page which is quite large, with a table of some 200 kBytes of data...
And an asp:button that takes AGES to fire the code-behind.

For instance the update progress displays for some 12 to 20 seconds before code executes!

The same code-behind fires in less than a second from a shorter page.
And Javascript onclick code fires instantly.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view state may be too large, causing all this data to travel back and forth with every postback. I suggest evaluating your view state and mitigating the display of large data via JS/JQuery on demand - on a page by page basis via ScriptService or generic handler (+JSON).

Comment: Gotcha! I wasn't aware ALL the viewstate was travelling back to the server in Ajax! And my ISP is soooo slow when it comes to upload date... I'll be better doing a location.assign in javascript and re-read the necessary data server-side on the newly prepared page... Let me just try that and then I'll accept ur answer.

Comment: Lol, ok. No problem. Are u using the MS Ajax framework or JQuery? I suggest trying it with JQuery DataTables plugin and either a script service or generic handler spitting your table data as json. Makes the page leaner, and loading times almost instant.

Comment: Using MS Ajax at the moment. Unfortunately I didn't found no simple yet well organized js tutorial explaining what to expect and day to day useful tips. And I don't have time to make my own experiments right now!